# how to enable sessions on online server for asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, xamarin.android

i have an android app that works online on Xamarin Android and with online web services and online database my problem is the sessions in web services is working god for localhost but when i use it on the server side it didn't work  here is apart of my code when i use the session in login method and the id of the user to use it in another method :
login method :

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]//Checks For Email And Password And Return The Type Of User
    public string Login(string Email, string Password)
    {
        SqlDataReader reader;
        Users us = new Users();
        int userid = -1;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DBConnection.ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT User_ID FROM Users where Email=@Email AND Password=@Password");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
            connection.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                userid = reader.GetInt32(0);

            }
            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
            if (userid != -1)
            {
                Session["userid"] = userid;
                return us.Usertype(userid);

            }
            else
                return "Some Thing Went Wrong Please Check Your Informatin";
        }
    }
```

and here is the method that i use the session in it :

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]//Return Shop id By Session
    public string getshopid()
    {
        int iduser = 0;
        iduser = Int32.Parse(Session["userid"].ToString());
        int shopid =0;
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader reader;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DBConnection.ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Owner_Shop_ID FROM Owner where Owner_User_ID="+iduser);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                connection.Open();

                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    shopid =reader.GetInt32(0);
                }

                reader.Close();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string em = ex.Message;
        }

        return shopid.ToString();
    }
```

is there some way to make session work on server side not just locally . am using smarterasp.net server

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't use session on shared hosting as it will impact to other sites on that server. You might need to contact your hosting provider directly to ask other solution that you can use. Basically, other option you can use cookies or Asp.net session state.